# CSS function code assistant / autocomplete in WebStorm / PhpStorm

Tags: css, function, autocomplete, phpstorm, webstorm

Is there any ways to show code assistant/autocomplete for CSS function in JetBrains product? I saw Atom did showed it and I couldn't find a way to do that in PhpStorm.

I can see that IDE could recognize the function, it's weird that it couldn't suggest anything when I was typing.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Completion for `transform` functions is provided since 2017.3 (see [WEB-27587](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27587)). Please try the [EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program):

[image]